# Cisco ASA 8.4(3); NAT multiple ports on public IP to private IP

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, nat

I have the following configuration on an ASA running 8.4 already;

```
object network SERVER-01
 host 192.168.0.1
!
object network SERVER-01
 nat (Inside,Outside) static interface service tcp 3389 5001
```

I have this config repeated several times to allow RDP to multiple machines behind the ASA, on different ports; 5001 forwards to one server, 5002 to another, and so on.

For this one server in the above config though, I want to forward port 5555 publicly to port 5555 at the same private IP, 192.168.0.1.

If I try to enter the above config but with different port numbers, it is overwritten, **I can't seem to *add* an additional NAT entry, only replace that one**. This indicates I can only have one port forwarded to each internal IP at a time. Is that correct, or can I forward various public ports to an internal host, but using some other method? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately from the [Configuring Network Object NAT](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa84/configuration/guide/nat_objects.html#wp1103116) documentation for 8.4 it states

> You can only define a single NAT rule for a given object; if you want to configure multiple NAT rules for an object, you need to create multiple objects with different names that specify the same IP address, for example, object network obj-10.10.10.1-01, object network obj-10.10.10.1-02, and so on.

So you will have to create multiple objects with the same host just different names.

Answer (score 5):

Create a second object with the same host

```
object network SERVER-02
 host 192.168.0.1
!
object network SERVER-02
 nat (Inside,Outside) static interface service tcp 5555 5555
```